# How to use view object instead of copy in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Using the following code

```
fn_t1 = glob("/T1/*.nii")
fn_fl = glob("/flair/*.nii")
fn_lb = glob("/label/*.nii")

dat_t1 = np.empty(shape=(len(fn_t1),250,250,74), dtype=np.float32)
dat_fl = np.empty(shape=(len(fn_fl),250,250,74), dtype=np.float32)
dat_lb = np.empty(shape=(len(fn_lb),250,250,74), dtype=np.float32)

npad = ((5,5),(5,5),(13,13))

for cnt, f in enumerate(fn_t1):
    dat_t1[cnt] = np.pad(nib.load(f).get_data(), pad_width=npad,mode='constant', constant_values=0)
for cnt, f in enumerate(fn_fl):
    dat_fl[cnt] = np.pad(nib.load(f).get_data(), pad_width=npad, mode='constant', constant_values=0)
for cnt, f in enumerate(fn_lb):
    dat_lb[cnt] = np.pad(nib.load(f).get_data(), pad_width=npad, mode='constant', constant_values=0)


idx = np.transpose(np.unravel_index(np.random.choice(np.prod(1847893),size=1000,replace=False),1847893))

rolling_lb = rolling_window(dat_lb,(1,27,27,27))
rolling_t1 = rolling_window(dat_t1,(1,27,27,27))
rolling_fl = rolling_window(dat_fl,(1,27,27,27))

input_t1 =  np.empty(shape=(1000,27,27,27), dtype=np.float32)

voxels = (rolling_lb[...,13,13,13] > 0)

start_time = time.time()

print('------------------------------------------------')
print(np.may_share_memory(rolling_t1,dat_t1))
print(np.may_share_memory(rolling_t1,rolling_t1[voxels[:]]))
```

you get this output:

```
True        
False
```

Question:

1 : I do not know why the second result is `False`.

2 : And i want to know how to change that `rolling_t1[voxels[:]]` to get `True` result.

Comment: `voxels` is a boolean array.  Indexing with a boolean array creates a copy - see the docs on `advanced indexing`.  The `[:]` does nothing.

Comment: Okay. I understand your comment. So I am thinking how to change that.

Comment: A view shares the original memory, but with a different start point, shape and/or strides.  A view does not `store` the indexing array(s). So a view is either a contiguous subset, or regular pattern (every other element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First question

What you see here is the difference between

[basic indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing)

> All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original array.

and [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)

> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a view).

So indexing with `voxels[:]` returns a copy.

#### Second question

You cannot index your array with arbitrary indices and get a view. To get a view, your indexing need to use constant steps, and slice contiguous areas of memory, i.e. conform to the requirements of basic indexing. This is generally not the case when indexing with boolean arrays.

Comment: I read basic indexing and advanced indexing.
And understand concepts. Thank you!